# Swipe to delete with phonegap

Tags: xcode, html, cordova, swipe, phonegap-build

I have been following a tutorial that ends up creating a web app for storing form input data locally (you can see the final proj here: http://mc-mobile-app.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

I am then using the files to test creating a native app with phonegap and Xcode - but I cant work out how to add a swipe to delete on the stored entries (one by one rather than just a delete of all in one go).

Is this possible using the above tools and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

write the followinf in your 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' delegate method of the tableView:

```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                                   action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft)];
   swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
   [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
   [swipeLeft release];
```

you mus write a handler "handleSwipeLeft:" which shows the delete button and then on click event of this button you can write the following code to delete the table row:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

where indexPaths is an array of indexes that you want to delete...
hope it helps... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - The app is an HTML5 app ported into phone gap - will that work? and if so where is it i enter that code?

Sorry this is literally my first attempt at an iPhone app
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same thing. 
The closest I can find is a jQuery-mobile plugin ..

http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/02/19/swipeButton-jQuery-Mobile-plugin-launches.-Millions-rejoice!